# Filter based on levels of column

Tags: r, dplyr

```
help <- data.frame(id = c(5, 5, 7, 7, 18, 18, 42, 42, 46, 46, 50, 51),
                   grade = c("a", "a", "b", "b", "c", "c", "d", "d", "e", "e", "w", "z"),
                   pass = c("yes", "no", "yes", "no", "no", "no", "yes", "no", "yes", "yes", "yes", "no"))
```

Using the help dataset, I want to:

- (1) keep ids with duplicate grade and a yes/no pass
- (2) then keep only the row that has a yes grade and drop the no
  grade row

With the hopes of having a dataset that looks like so:

```
  id grade pass
   5     a  yes
   7     b  yes
  42     d  yes
  46     e  yes
  46     e  yes
```

I attempted to use...

```
help %>% group_by(id, grade, pass) %>% filter(pass == "yes" & pass == "no")
```

but even that doesn't work as it erases everything and outputs an empty df.

Comment: You need all the id with a duplicate grade? Is that the first question?

Comment: I'm hoping for duplicate grade and both a yes and no row for that duplicate grade

Comment: I think your last row in the 'dataset that looks like so' should be `w` rather than `e`.

Comment: Dear all, I think the row 11 `50     w  yes` should not be returned as the OP wants `ids` with duplicate grades, while row 11 has no duplicate grades.

Comment: Yes that is correct, @www

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can `group_by` based on `id` and `grade` and then filter when count number is larger than 1 and `pass` is `yes`.

```
library(dplyr)

help %>%
  group_by(id, grade) %>%
  filter(n() > 1, pass %in% "yes") %>%
  ungroup()
# # A tibble: 5 x 3
#      id grade pass 
#   <dbl> <fct> <fct>
# 1  5.00 a     yes  
# 2  7.00 b     yes  
# 3 42.0  d     yes  
# 4 46.0  e     yes  
# 5 46.0  e     yes
```

Comment: thanks, any ideas how to merge that back into the dataset that includes id 50 and 51?

Comment: thanks @www... i took the long route and pulled those observations out of the dataset, then merged them all back together. i'll try the `right_join()` too. cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Using base `r` a solution could be:

```
help <- data.frame(id = c(5, 5, 7, 7, 18, 18, 42, 42, 46, 46, 50, 51),
    grade = c("a", "a", "b", "b", "c", "c", "d", "d", "e", "e", "w", "z"),
    pass = c("yes", "no", "yes", "no", "no", "no", "yes", "no", "yes", "yes", "yes", "no"))

# Keep duplicate Id and grades. The trick is to find duplicate from
# from start and then from last
help2 <- help[duplicated((help[,1:2])) | duplicated(help[,1:2], fromLast = TRUE),]


    # Filter for the pass
   help2[help2$pass == "yes",]

#   id grade pass
#1   5     a  yes
#3   7     b  yes
#7  42     d  yes
#9  46     e  yes
#10 46     e  yes
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 subset(help,!duplicated(help)&pass=="yes")
   id grade pass
1   5     a  yes
3   7     b  yes
7  42     d  yes
9  46     e  yes
11 50     w  yes
```

Answer (score 0):

So I load it in:

```
og_help <- data.frame(id = c(5, 5, 7, 7, 18, 18, 42, 42, 46, 46, 50, 51),
                   grade = c("a", "a", "b", "b", "c", "c", "d", "d", "e", "e", "w", "z"),
                   pass = c("yes", "no", "yes", "no", "no", "no", "yes", "no", "yes", "yes", "yes", "no"))
```

Then I return a unique set of the rows:

```
help <- unique(og_help)
```

And subset only those which have the `pass` variable set to `yes`.

```
help <- help[ which(help$pass == "yes"), ]
```

This outputs the following:

```
   id grade pass
1   5     a  yes
3   7     b  yes
7  42     d  yes
9  46     e  yes
11 50     w  yes
```